# Creating dynamic library on Mac OSX using clang++

Tags: c++, makefile, clang++, dylib

I wanted to learn how to make a shared library in C++. So I found some logic to generate Mandelbrot PPM images, and encapsulated it in `src/mandelbrot.cpp` (with accompanying header file `include/mandelbrot.cpp`). Directory tree looks like:

```
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── include
│   └── mandelbrot.h
├── lib
│   └── mandelbrot.dylib
└── src
    ├── client.cpp
    ├── main
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── mandelbrot.cpp
    └── mandelbrot.o
```

The goal is for `src/client.cpp` to use `lib/mandelbrot.dylib` to draw the fractal without having access to `src/mandelbrot.cpp` or `src/mandelbrot.o`.

Makefile:

```
.PHONY=clean

main: src/mandelbrot.o
    clang++ src/main.cpp -o src/main src/mandelbrot.o -I ./include

src/mandelbrot.o:
    clang++ -c src/mandelbrot.cpp -o src/mandelbrot.o -I ./include

clean:
    rm src/*.o
    rm lib/*.dylib

lib/mandelbrot.dylib:
    clang++ -dynamiclib -o lib/mandelbrot.dylib src/mandelbrot.cpp -I ./include

src/client: lib/mandelbrot.dylib
    clang++ src/client.cpp -o src/client -L ./lib -I ./include
```

Running the executable without the dylib works:

```sh
$ make main
clang++ src/main.cpp -o src/main src/mandelbrot.o -I ./include
$ ./src/main  # runs fine!
```

But I can't get my shared library to link when compiling `src/client.cpp`:

```sh
$ make src/client
clang++ src/client.cpp -o src/client -L ./lib -I ./include
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "fractal::Mandelbrot::writeToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in client-e344c7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [src/client] Error 1
```

Even though the symbol seems to be in the dylib:

```
$ file lib/mandelbrot.dylib 
lib/mandelbrot.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

$ nm -C lib/mandelbrot.dylib | grep writeToFile
0000000000001460 T fractal::Mandelbrot::writeToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)
```

I'm trying to dig in deeper and understand the linking/compilation process. How do I make the setup I have work to demonstrate what I want to do?

Comment: You've added the path to the library, but you need to explicitly link it. You can do that by adding:

`-Llib/ -lmandelbrot`

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work. When I run `clang++ src/client.cpp -o src/client -L ./lib -l mandelbrot -I ./include` I get `ld: library not found for -lmandelbrot`. I'm learning though, why do we need to explicitly link it? and where does the `"mandelbrot"` come from?

Comment: So, you have a group of functions in the dynamic library. Your application defined by src/client.cpp knows about those functions because the header file specifies their definition - that's why you get the 'undefined symbol' error message - take symbol here to mean function. You need to explicitly link because otherwise the compiler doesn't know where to look to find the implementations of those functions.

Comment: OK, but how does the naming work? I'm still confused on how to think about the name `-l` flag requires and how C++ understands to look for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try naming your library like libmandelbrot.dylib to match the -lmandelbrot flag

Comment: So that worked! ... but why?? does the way you use a dynamic library really depend on how you name the file? that seems crazy. where does the naming come from? I don't think I can mark this as solved until I understand what's going on here.

Comment: It is the sensible but arbitrary convention used by the linker systems.  When we use -lc or -ljeg  se are asking for libc.[so|dynlib|a] and libjpeg.[so|dynlib|a]  depending on the system and whether we are linking with static or dynamic libraries.  
do a **man ld** in the console and look for **-l namespec** . There is documented.
I did exactly the same as you. I remember. Believe me we are not alone in this boat :-)

Comment: nailed it! c++ is weird sometimes. I put some more information in another answer to help anyone who comes across this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to @Daniel for finding the answer, but a bit about why.

I can make the compilation work by renaming `mandelbrot.dylib` -> `libmandelbrot.dylib` as suggested by @daniel's answer.

I dug into `man ld` (the linker) and found the following definition:

```
-lx    This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or libx.a in the library search path.  If string x is of the form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places, but without prepending
       `lib' or appending `.a' or `.dylib' to the filename.
```

Thus, if you want to arbitrarily name your dynamically loaded libraries (and for some reason don't like the magic of prepending libxxxx to the name, you'd have to do this (I have confirmed this works):

```
lib/whatever.o:
    clang++ -dynamiclib -o lib/whatever.o src/mandelbrot.cpp -I ./include

src/client: lib/whatever.o
    clang++ src/client.cpp -o src/client -L ./lib -I ./include -l whatever.o
```

**TL;DR** = By having the `-l` option as a filename ending in `.o`, the linker looks directly in the directory specified by `-L` for the exact filename specified in `-l`. Otherwise `-l foo -L /path/` searches for `/path/libfoo.[dylib|a]`